# How to count list of dictionaries key's in Jinja

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, jinja2

I have list of `dictionaries` i want to count how many times `"P"` appears in that dictionaries
and update `total` as `key` and give `value` count

```
{% set my_list = [
  {'key1': "P",'key2': "P",'key3': "P",'key4': "P"},
  {'key1': "P",'key2': "P",'key1': "",'key3': "P",'key4': "P"}, 
  {'key1': "P",'key2': "P",'key3': "",'key4': "P"}
] %}
```

My code is :

```
{% for my_dict in my_list %}

  {% set count = 0 %}

  {% for key, value in my_dict.items() %}

    {% if value == 'P' %}

      {% set count = count + 1 %}

    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}

 {% set _ = emp.update({'total': count}) %}  

{% endfor %}
```

This code is not incrementing count instead of incrementing its giving 0 in all dictionary i don't know how to do it

expecting output :

```
[
 {'key1': 'P', 'key2': 'P', 'key3': 'P', 'key4': 'P', 'total': 4},
 {'key1': '', 'key2': 'P', 'key3': 'P', 'key4': 'P', 'total': 3},  
 {'key1': 'P', 'key2': 'P', 'key3': '', 'key4': 'P', 'total': 3}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple [`{% set %}` assignment](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#assignments) has limited scope (the current block), you have to use the namespace object instead.

```
{% set counter = namespace(p=0) %}
{% for my_dict in my_list %}
  {% set counter.p = 0 %}{# Reset counter #}
  {% for key, value in my_dict.items() %}
    {% if value == 'P' %}
      {% set counter.p = counter.p + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% set _ = my_dict.update({'total': counter.p}) %}{# Update dictionary with total #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks @dauros I'm new in Jinja why you declared {% set counter = namespace(p=0) %} and how its work

Comment: Jinja's namespace object is a global variable inside a template. Like a global variable inside a Python script. You can access its attributes (in this example `counter.p`, but you can name it anything and can have multiple) everywhere inside the template file. Inside the loop I just increase the value of `counter.p` attribute each time the condition is satisfied.